# Story where low-level dungeons had been overexploited, causing issues because there was no way for early adventurers to survive and level up

Tags: story-identification

I was reading a Facebook meme where a 10-year-old pointed out that the Big Bad should put their lair next to a small village so that the adventurers always get wiped out before they can level up to be threats in their journey to the villain's lair, and it sparked a memory of recently reading about a work of fiction (I want to say it was a manga, but it might have been a novel or a short story) where something like this happened. Not that the Big Bad did so intentionally, but rather that overexploitation of resources had led to all of the easy dungeons getting wiped out, and the people of the world realizing that the experienced adventurers were going to age out of the system soon, and there was no way for lower level adventurers to survive to level up, since the threats they faced were either too little to get XP quickly (hunting common vermin and the like) or were too deadly (higher level dungeons). It reminded me of a commentary I saw recently about how machine-assisted systems were resulting in a dearth of engineers learning in real-world scenarios, creating the expertise necessary to ensure that the automated systems run correctly.

### The meme

[image: Meme]

I remember reading the reference to the story in the last year or so, 2020-2021, although I did not read it myself (I think I noted it as "something to check out when I have time" but I failed to actually write it down, and now I find myself curious again.

Comment: Out of curiosity (though it could also help the research), got a link to the meme?

Comment: Not quite the same, but there is a light novel/anime "Suppose a Kid from the Last Dungeon Boonies Moved to a Starter Town" about a boy who grew up in one of the most dangerous regions of the world, then was massively overpowered when moving to the starter town.

Comment: Please add a couple of paragraph breaks?